# What exactly is the negative impact of placing page file on SSD?

Tags: ssd, pagefile, lifespan

I see frequent mentions that placing page file on SSD is good for performance but bad for SSD's lifespan (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/588858/should-the-pagefile-be-placed-on-the-ssd-or-the-hdd) on SU). But nothing I saw had any citations, especially ones backed by actual data.

Is there any reasonable measurement backed non-anecdotal assessment of just what exactly the impact on SSD's lifespand is?

E.g. will it cause SSD to fail in 1 year 50% of time, or shorten it from average 5 years to average 4 years etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sigh*. I'm pretty tired of debunking this, and I'm copying exactly what I said [previously](https://superuser.com/questions/990710/how-damaged-is-my-ssd-disc/990715#990715)

> The idea that SSDs are fragile snowflakes that will melt under the
>   white heat of data is a bit of a mistake.
>
> Many tests have been done where drives have been torture tested - tech
>   report did one [with last generation drives](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead), here's an [ongoing
>   one](http://ssdendurancetest.com/) and basically its PRETTY hard to kill a modern SSD by
>   excessive writes.

If it dies prematurely, its more likely to be due to other things.

You're going to want your pagefile on a SSD - If you have tons of ram, you're barely going to touch it except when needed.

If you don't, the fast SSD will be a better place to put a pagefile.

I tend to treat my systems as if my drives would die any day, and back up so... I'm probably a little less worried, but I'm doubtful it'll have a major effect on drive lifespans

From Jamie Hanrahan's [link in the comments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2009/05/05/support-and-qa-for-solid-state-drives/)

I found this gem

> **Should the pagefile be placed on SSDs?**
>
> Yes. Most pagefile operations are small random reads or larger
>   sequential writes, both of which are types of operations that SSDs
>   handle well.

And quite a bit more - its worth a read on the source.

In essence the things SSDs are good at (fast reads) and the sort of files that use a SSD efficiently (large ones) are both what the pagefile is.

The even go on to say

> In fact, given typical pagefile reference patterns and the favorable
>   performance characteristics SSDs have on those patterns, there are few
>   files better than the pagefile to place on an SSD.

So. Microsoft *recommends* using your SSD for your pagefile.

Comment: I agree completely. Microsoft agrees too, and they have actual data to prove it. _"Most pagefile operations are small random reads or larger sequential writes, both of which are types of operations that SSDs handle well. [...] In fact, given typical pagefile reference patterns and the favorable performance characteristics SSDs have on those patterns, there are few files better than the pagefile to place on an SSD."_  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2009/05/05/support-and-qa-for-solid-state-drives/

Comment: Oh, well, and since you did I deleted that comment, so now your reply comment is kinda hanging out there. :) On topic, I would also add this: If one is still concerned about pagefile writes wearing out an SSD, there is a simple answer - if you can install a second drive: Get a small (hence cheap) SSD, install that along with your primary, and put your pagefile on the little one. When/if it wears out (likely years from now), replace it. (But... if your pagefile IO is really a bottleneck on your machine you might be better off spending the money on more RAM. )

Comment: I typically replace the hdds on older laptops with the *cheapest* ssds I can find. As long as they do AHCI, the performance improvement is dramatic. I do have my home setup designed that I can afford to lose at least one hard drive at a time, so I'm personally less concerned about that.